# Syncing Uncommited Changes Between Computers

Tags: git, version-control, git-annex

During the day I work with multiple computers a latop and two desktops. Currently I keep all my repositories in my dropbox folder (I don't push pull to dropbox) so I can keep my uncommited changes synced between machines. I want to drop dropbox in favor of git-annex but due to limitations of git I can not keep my source folder in git-annex thus no way to sync uncommited changes using git-annex. Is there a technique for syncing uncommited stuff across computers with git alone without messing the history for the other developers.

Comment: Can you use a source control system to sync files it doesn't know about? I strongly suspect the answer is no...

Comment: Why don't you just use your own repository?

Comment: just commit it to your own branch, and push/pull that. Why would it affect anyone else?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are working in your separate branch, you can commit changes while they are not actually ready. To reduce number of work-in-progress commits, you have 2 choices:

1. Amend your work-in-progress commit every time. But that would require you to force-push your branch. That is only acceptable if no one else uses your branch.
2. Keep making commits until you're done. Then, when merging your branch to master, squeeze all your commits to a single one.